# Primitive $2^n$ centralizer group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is this true that for all positive integer $n$?

> There is no primitive $2^n$ centralizer group.

We know that, there exist $n$-centralizer groups for $n\neq 2, 3$, and there exists a primitive $n$-centralizer group for all odd $n\neq 3$.

Comment: What is an n-centralizer group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little background on what Babak is asking about:

A group G is said to be an **n-centralizer** group if { C<sub>G</sub>(z) : z in G } has exactly n elements.  A group is said to be a **primitive n-centralizer group** if both G and G/Z(G) are n-centralizer groups.  The very enjoyable paper Belcastro–Sherman (1994) shows that if G is 4-centralizer, then G/Z(G) is the Klein four-group.  Since the Klein four-group is 1-centralizer, there is no primitive 4-centralizer group.

> Belcastro, Sarah Marie; Sherman, Gary J.
>   Counting centralizers in finite groups.
>   Math. Mag. 67 (1994), no. 5, 366–374.
>   MR[1307800](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1307800)
>   DOI:[10.2307/2690998](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2690998)

This is well suited to beginning group theory students.

However, the problem was taken up by other people, and in Ashrafi–Taeri (2005), conjecture 2.5 suggests that there is no primitive 2<sup>n</sup>-centralizer group.

> Ashrafi, Ali Reza; Taeri, Bijan.
>   Classification of finite groups by the number of element centralizers.
>   Groups St. Andrews 2005. Vol. 1, 148–157, 
>   London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 339,
>   Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2007.
>   MR[2327320](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2327320) Google:[books](http://books.google.com/books?id=EUkaQBFMOtAC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148)

I don't see much progress on this, other than the case 2<sup>n</sup>=8 settled by:

> Abdollahi, A.; Jafarian Amiri, S. M.; Hassanabadi, A. Mohammadi.
>   Groups with specific number of centralizers.
>   Houston J. Math. 33 (2007), no. 1, 43–57.
>   MR[2287843](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2287843)
>   Author's [preprint](http://sci.ui.ac.ir/~a.abdollahi/PDF/2006-2.pdf).

Presumably Babak should write the authors and ask if they are aware of any further progress.  Ali Reza Ashrafi in particular wrote quite a few papers on this topic in the early part of last decade, and so probably has kept at least some contact with the problem.

---

In case you want to explore some examples in GAP, you might like to use (or improve) the functions I wrote to understand the problem:

```
centralizerCount := function(g)
  local inn;
  inn := Action( g, AsSet(g), OnPoints );
  return Size( AsSet( List( [1..Size(g)], i -> Stabilizer(inn,i) ) ) );
end;

gs := AllSmallGroups([1..60], g -> centralizerCount(g), 8 );;
gid := List(gs, IdGroup);
zid := List(gs, g -> IdGroup(g/Center(g)) );
counterexamples := Intersection( gid, zid );
```

Notice that the for any group G in the list 8-centralizer groups `gs`, the inner automorphism group G/Z(G) is no longer 8-centralizing.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the help. I will. But don't you think GAP can help us for this problem. I think, I should probe the case with GAP first. Again Thanks.